# private pypiserver with read write restrictions to user/password pairs

Tags: docker, authentication, pypiserver

I'm using https://hub.docker.com/r/pypiserver/pypiserver to host a private pypi server.
The `-a` flag allows me to restrict which actions need to be authenticated.
The `-P` flag allows me to pass in user/password pairs.

I need:

- all actions requiring authentication
- Only certain user/passwords can read+write
- Others can only read

Reading that page, this doesn't seem to be possible? How can I achieve this?